# How to create an ssl for a domain that is pointed from the hosts file?

Tags: ssl, https

Let's say I edit my hosts file on my computer to make google.com point to my VPS server IP, and the server has virtual host/server block for google.com configured trough Apache or Nginx.

So when I visit google.com it'll load whatever is configured on the server through HTTP, how can I make it HTTPS? can I do it with Let's Encrypt? I have tried to edit the hosts file on the VPS itself and then run cert-bot, but that didn't work.

in simple words: I don't own the domain, but would like to own it on my machine only trough https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't own the domain, but would like to own it on my machine only trough https.

You can't do it with a publicly trusted certificate. You can create your own PKI with your own trusted root CA which you import as trusted in your own browser. Then you can create the server certificates you want with this CA and since your browser trusts this CA it will also accept your own certificates.

There are many resources online which [describe how to create your own CA](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+your+own+certificate+authority), like [here](https://medium.com/@hugomejia74/how-to-create-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development-3b97573c7bb5) or [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Be-Your-Own-Certificate-Authority) or [here](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/).